# What is the correct installation process for using Bootstrap 4 Source in my projects

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

OK so I have read the docs on this and have not even attempted it as it just goes over my head.

I have a project folder:

```
example.com
```

I want to get used to using the full functionality of bootstrap by being able to customize the variables and which files get compiled on specific projects.

I have node.js installed on my machine so I have access to npm, grunt etc.

I have downloaded the source files form [here](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download/), but I am not against using npm to install if that is a better option. **Note** I would need to know how compile from the `node_modules` into files I can link to in the `.html` files.

My main question would be, if I download the source files from the site to use in my project, where in the file structure do the source files go in relation to the rest of the project and my own SCSS and JS.

Hope you can help!
Craig

Answer (score 0):

If your project's folder structure is;

```
project
|-- node_modules
|-- public
|   |-- css
|   |-- img
|   |-- js
|   |-- index.html
|-- package.json
```

then,

```
$ npm install bootstrap
```

will install the bootstrap to `./node_modules/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css`.

**Alternatively**, you can use bootstrap **CDN** in your pages like;

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

More info is at Bootstrap's official [installation guide](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/).